# How can I access the secondary text of a parent widget created in a loop in Kivymd?

Tags: python, list, inheritance, kivy, kivymd

I have a list of strings. In the loop, I create 10 MDExpansionPanel and for each secondary_text field in the TwoLineIconListItem I assign a value from the list. Also in TwoLineIconListItem I have a LeftIconWidget on click that needs the current text from secoundary_text to be added to the per = [] variable. It seems to me that I have tried all the options. Here's what's at the moment:

```
per = []
class Test(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
         for i in range(10):
            self.root.ids.boxCul.add_widget(
                MDExpansionPanel(
                    icon=os.path.join(images_path, "logo", "kivymd-icon-128.png"),
                    content=TwoLineIconListItem(IconLeftWidget(icon='star-plus-outline', on_press=lambda x: MYFUNTCION), text='', secondary_text=culList[i]),
                    panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelThreeLine(
                        text='Text',
                        secondary_text="Secondary text",
                        tertiary_text="Tertiary text",
                    )
                )
            )
```

I can't figure out how to access the secondary_text of the parent widget because it's being created in a loop. It seems to me that it is impossible to get this text